# How do I add records which do not already exists in a table with an add query

Tags: ms-access

I'd like the following add query to only add records which are not already in the table.

```
INSERT INTO tbl_TRUCK_train_cv ( handling, [text] )
SELECT qryTRUCK_CV_train_CW_2.cv_2 AS handling, "TRUCK: " & [tblTRUCKInformation].[fldTextTXT] & Chr(10) & Chr(13) & "train: " & [tbltrainInformation].[fldTextTXT] AS [text]
FROM (qryTRUCK_CV_train_CW_2 LEFT JOIN tbltrainInformation ON qryTRUCK_CV_train_CW_2.cw = tbltrainInformation.fldID) LEFT JOIN tblTRUCKInformation ON qryTRUCK_CV_train_CW_2.cv = tblTRUCKInformation.fldID
WHERE (((qryTRUCK_CV_train_CW_2.cv)<>""));
```

E.G.
The data in the table `tbl_TRUCK_train_cv` is as follows:

```
id | handling   | text
-------------------------
"" | "CV1/CW1"  | "bla"
"" | "CV4/CW7"  | "bla"
```

The data in the add query is as follows:

```
id | handling   | text
-------------------------
"" | "CV3/CW12" | "bla"
"" | "CV4/CW7"  | "bla"
```

The add query should only add `"" | "CV3/CW12" | "bla"` as this records is not already in table `tbl_TRUCK_train_cv`

I have no clue how to solve this.
In this particular case the table is populated from different queries which might have duplicate values.

Comment: Add a _unique index_ to the fields that define uniqueness of a record in the target table (`tbl_TRUCK_train_cv`).

Comment: Setting the `Indexed` to `Yes (No Duplicates)` causes the query to err.    Or might I have misunderstood your suggestion

Comment: If you run it from code. try calling `DoCmd.SetWarnings = False`. Or use as source a query where you include an outer join to the target table and filters on the ID of that to be _Null_.

Comment: What are 'duplicate' values in your data - what field(s) determine record uniqueness? Edit question to show sample data and desired result as text tables.

Comment: You can work around the problem using vba. loop through a recordset based on the add query.  For each row check if it is in tbl_Truck_train_cv and if not insert it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, this can be done in an Insert query similar to the one you have crafted in your question.  Let me walk you through it one step at a time:

First, lets start with a query that joins the table and the query on the field '[handling]', it looks like this:

```
    SELECT qryTRUCK_CV_train_CW_2.handling 
    FROM qryTRUCK_CV_train_CW_2 INNER JOIN 
    tbl_TRUCK_train_cv ON qryTRUCK_CV_train_CW_2.handling = tbl_TRUCK_train_cv.handling;
```

Now, you want a query that will find records in the query [qryTRUCK_CV_train_CW_2] that are NOT in the table [tbl_TRUCK_train_cv] .  To do this, change the Join statement to be a LEFT JOIN.  This will show all records in the query [qryTRUCK_CV_train_CW_2] regardless if there is a matching record in the table [tbl_TRUCK_train_cv].

```
    SELECT qryTRUCK_CV_train_CW_2.handling
    FROM qryTRUCK_CV_train_CW_2 
    LEFT JOIN tbl_TRUCK_train_cv ON qryTRUCK_CV_train_CW_2.handling = 
    tbl_TRUCK_train_cv.handling;
```

And finally, add the criteria WHERE [tbl_TRUCK_train_cv].handling Is Null.

```
    SELECT qryTRUCK_CV_train_CW_2.handling
    FROM qryTRUCK_CV_train_CW_2 LEFT JOIN tbl_TRUCK_train_cv ON 
    qryTRUCK_CV_train_CW_2.handling = tbl_TRUCK_train_cv.handling
    WHERE (((tbl_TRUCK_train_cv.handling) Is Null));
```

This WHERE clause will limit the records to just ones that are in the Query but not in the table!

You are almost there.

Next, lets make this a grouping query in case there are duplicates in the field [handling] in the Query.

```
    SELECT qryTRUCK_CV_train_CW_2.handling
    FROM qryTRUCK_CV_train_CW_2 LEFT JOIN tbl_TRUCK_train_cv ON 
    qryTRUCK_CV_train_CW_2.handling = tbl_TRUCK_train_cv.handling
    WHERE (((tbl_TRUCK_train_cv.handling) Is Null))
    GROUP BY qryTRUCK_CV_train_CW_2.handling;
```

And finally, to take these results and insert them into the table [tbl_TRUCK_train_cv]

```
    INSERT INTO tbl_TRUCK_train_cv ( handling )
    SELECT qryTRUCK_CV_train_CW_2.handling
    FROM qryTRUCK_CV_train_CW_2 LEFT JOIN tbl_TRUCK_train_cv ON 
    qryTRUCK_CV_train_CW_2.handling = tbl_TRUCK_train_cv.handling
    WHERE (((tbl_TRUCK_train_cv.handling) Is Null))
    GROUP BY qryTRUCK_CV_train_CW_2.handling;
```

Comment: Thank you MKingham, I hoped for a less cumbersome solution, but it works!